# Get the SQL that would be executed from a certain method or named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given an ActiveRecord method or `named_scope` chain, is there a way to return the SQL that will get executed, without actually running it?

e.g.

```
Vote.positive.count.sql #=> "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE value > 0"
```

Is there a built-in way to do this or a plug-in that offers this functionality? If not, any clues to where I can start to build my own plug-in or at least a solution for this current project.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been so long but I thought it'd be useful to point out that Rails3 will have support for this on any scope/finder/model method that ends up hitting the DB.

Answer (score 4):

You can get information out of a named scope like so:

```
Vote.positive.proxy_options
```

As for getting the full SQL statement, ActiveRecord puts this together using a protected method called `construct_finder_sql`.

So you could try this:

```
Vote.positive.send(:construct_finder_sql, {})
```

The method used is different for calculation queries:

```
Vote.positive.send(:construct_calculation_sql, :count, :id, {})
```

in both cases the empty hash argument can have keys like `:conditions`, `:order`, `:limit` or some additional options you may discover by inspecting the bodies of these methods.