# How can I get SQL statement created by ActiveRecord#find without actually executing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I am using `will_paginate` with some complicated queries and it is unable to correctly calculate number of total records (in order to display proper number of page links) - namely because of grouping by multiple columns.

So, I am intending to get the SELECT query which would be used to retrieve ALL records, without actually executing it, and wrap it with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` manually, in order to get the number of records.

Any ideas how to do it?

Edit: I am using Rails 2.3.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the SQL that would be executed from a certain method or named_scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974020/get-the-sql-that-would-be-executed-from-a-certain-method-or-named-scope)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For Rails 3:

Check out the ActiveRecord::Relation docs at the [Rails 3 docs](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0/).

```
# get the relation
rel = User.complex_scope.chained_complex_scope

# get the SQL
# this does not execute the query
sql = rel.to_sql

# find out how many records
# this executes the query behind the scenes
count = rel.size
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind when we migrate to 3. I forgot to mention that we're still using 2.3.x, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

It seems thatm in Rails 2.x, a private method called [`ActiveRecord::Base#construct_finder_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/construct_finder_sql/class) could be used, I need to test it more and see whether it will work for me:

```
ActionType.find(:all, :select => 'hosted, top_action_type, count(*) as count', :group => 'hosted, top_action_type').count
#=> 6
sql = ActionType.send :construct_finder_sql, :select => 'hosted, top_action_type, count(*) as count', :group => 'hosted, top_action_type'
#=> "SELECT hosted, top_action_type, count(*) as count FROM "action_types"  GROUP BY hosted, top_action_type"
ActionType.count_by_sql "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (#{sql}) a"
#=> 6
```

Comment: Tested and actually works OK. I guess I should accept own answer. :/

Comment: Is there a way to add *:include* as well?

Answer (score 3):

I know the question asks "without executing it", but the `#explain` method is super useful and should at least be mentioned here. It is extremely useful for debugging slow queries.

Note: It does execute the query though.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/active_record_querying.html#running-explain

```
$ User.where("users.email LIKE '%longford%'").explain

  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (users.email LIKE '%longford%')
 => EXPLAIN for: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (users.email LIKE '%gmail%')
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    5 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4 and above use `to_sql` as explained in the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814828/163203).

#### Original answer

Sometime ago, I used a plugin called [sql_display](http://github.com/radar/sql_display) for this.

```
>> Post.sql
=> "SELECT * FROM \"posts\""

>> Post.sql(:order => "id DESC")
=> "SELECT * FROM \"posts\" ORDER id DESC"

>> Post.scoped({}).sql
=> "SELECT * FROM \"posts\""

>> Post.count_sql
=> "SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM \"posts\""
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Do you perhaps know whether it constructs SQL mimicking AR behaviour, or wraps AR somehow? I.e. can I rely that it will give exactly the same query `AR#find` would?

Comment: that link 404's. can't find that gem referenced on the interwebs.

Comment: @gabe AR now supports `to_sql`. You don't need special gems for this. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814828/163203 answer for more details

Comment: @HarishShetty yea, i know about `to_sql`. i can't quite remember the nuanced thing i was looking for now... i think i was trying to find something that would dump sql for complex count things.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Rails 2.x this is actually quite hard. I've posted a similar question on Stack Overflow before and ended up digging deep into the source code of Rails to find a way. It just isn't architected in a way to allow this.

What I ended up doing was running the query in a transaction that I rolled back, and for the length of the transaction setting the logger to my own StringIO object that I could read after.

This is from memory but hopefully you understand it enough to adjust it if it doesn't work:

```
Model.transaction do 
  Model.logger = str = StringIO.new
  Model.complex_scope.chained_complex_scope
  Model.logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
  str.rewind
  str = str.read

  # perform some regex on str to get the actual query

  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

It is ugly as hell and I never liked it (I wrapped it in a `sql { Model. complex_scope.chained_complex_scope }`) but it kinda worked for me (I only used it in development though, so I had some tolerance for errors)